# Outlook Appointment Reply instead of Respond through C#

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem, com-object

I wanted to reply all to an output appointment instead of respond through c# code.

I am able to iterate through all the appointments of today but in .net 3.5 I could not find an option to Reply All to the appointment. The only option available is Respond or Send appointment as attachment.

I basically wants to open (Display) the reply all window of the appointment with some custom body.

Please guide how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with .Net. Outlook Object Model exposes the ReplyAll method only on the MeetingItem, MailItem, SharingItem, and MobileItem objects. That method is not exposed by the AppointmentItem object.

Comment: There is Reply All option available in outlook when I open any appointment. I want to implement same through C# code.

Comment: For an appointment, instead of respond I wanted to reply with some text in the body.